How to convert a datetime string to another time zone
I have a string "2024-09-19 14:20:45" in given time zone say  "America/Los_Angeles".
In javascript how can I convert it to datetime string in another time zone "timezone2" say "America/New_York" (three hours earlier than Los Angeles)?
How can I get "2024-09-19 17:20:45" in the above example for "America/New_York" in Javascript ?

Lets try that in Luxon, since JS has crummy timezone handling


const convertTimeZone = (inputDateStr, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone) => {
  const { DateTime } = luxon; // Access Luxon from global object

  // Parse the date in the fromTimeZone
  const dateInFromZone = DateTime.fromFormat(inputDateStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', {
    zone: fromTimeZone
  });

  // Convert to the target time zone
  const dateInTargetZone = dateInFromZone.setZone(toTimeZone);

  // Return the formatted date in the target time zone
  return dateInTargetZone.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
};

const inputDateStr = "2024-09-19 14:20:45";
const timezoneLA = "America/Los_Angeles";
const timezoneNY = "America/New_York";
const timezoneTaipei = "Asia/Taipei";


console.log('Time in NY', convertTimeZone(inputDateStr, timezoneLA, timezoneNY));


console.log('Time in Taipei', convertTimeZone(inputDateStr, timezoneLA, timezoneTaipei))
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>






const inputDateStr = "2024-09-19 14:20:45";
const timezone1 = "America/Los_Angeles";
const timezone2 = "America/New_York";

// Convert inputDateStr to a Date object in UTC, assuming it's in timezone1
const dateInLA = new Date(`${inputDateStr} UTC`);

// Use Intl.DateTimeFormat to convert the date to timezone2
const options = {
  timeZone: timezone2,
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
};

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options);
const parts = dateFormatter.formatToParts(dateInLA);

const formattedDate = `${parts[4].value}-${parts[0].value}-${parts[2].value} ${parts[6].value}:${parts[8].value}:${parts[10].value}`;

console.log(formattedDate); // "2024-09-19 17:20:45"



In this approach:
new Date(): We parse the string and assume it's UTC.
Intl.DateTimeFormat: This is used to format the date into the desired time zone, America/New_York.

I am in Asia Taipei. How comes my browser gives me the wrong answer "2024-09-19 10:20:45" ?

The timestamp passed to the Date constructor is not in a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least considers it an invalid date. To be compliant, the format should be like "2024-09-19T14:20:45Z". Regardless, this answer doesn't address the problem of parsing the timestamp relative to a particular location such as "America/New_York", which would include adjustments for daylight saving where applicable.
